# In Ruby, why aren't variable names in the stack trace?

Tags: ruby, debugging, exception, stack-trace

In a rails app with associations (Such as `Post belongs_to user`), a common exception is this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
```

Ubiquitously, this causes beginners to believe that `user` is nil.  Why don't we have more intuitive errors, such as the following?

```
NoMethodError: `@post' is a nil:NilClass and doesn't have the method `user'
```

EDIT: Why is this being downvoted? The question is legitimate. I'd like to know if there is a technical reason preventing this.

Comment: They downvote all the time. Never mind.

Comment: I suspect they're downvoting for exactly the reason that @CharlesOliverNutter says in his first sentence. It's a pretty clear message, "nil doesn't have a method called 'user'". That, plus the line number, tells me a lot. If I can't tell what variable would have caused it then I'll restructure my code so its more apparent, but usually it'll be the one with a `.user` tacked onto it.

Comment: I regularly tutor people who are beginning both Ruby and Rails at once.  My understanding is that it is easy to be overwhelmed, and frustrated when something doesn't work, and to quickly read `user` and `nil` before making some change and reloading the page.  :-(  We've learned to pay attention to the line number and such.  There's probably a better place for this discussion, but I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I disagree with the original assertion. The message clearly says that user is an undefined method, not a variable or a value. I'm not sure how someone could think user is a variable based on this message.

However the answer to your question is that by the time the "user" method is called, the target object has already been loaded from whatever variable referenced it. The call logic for invoking "user" doesn't know anything about where that object came from. It could have been a local variable, an instance variable, a constant...there's no way to tell. Also, the Rails "whiny nil" logic happens in a method_missing implementation, far, far away from the original access of the object; the context of the original variable lookup is not even in scope anymore.